# Ограничение использования памяти Python

Tags: python, ram

Можно ли как то в коде задать ограничение на использование ОЗУ исполняемым кодом ? Пробовал через subprocess , но как будто эффекта ноль, никаких ограничений не создается , как и ошибок.

ChatGPT предложил это решение:

```
    max_memory_limit = 20971520000


    subprocess.run(["wmic", "process", "where", "name='python.exe'", "set", "VirtualBytesLimit=" + str(max_memory_limit)])
```

но оно вообще как будто ничего не меняет в работе кода.

(скажу сразу , докер - не вариант)
upd: система , где это все должно работать - windows

Comment: В какой операционной системе? wmic намекает на винду, но стоит указать это явно в вопросе

Comment: Если ограничить память снаружи то питон просто грохнется когда понадобится больше. Может просто кодить надо с учетом памяти?

Comment: ЧатГПТ преложил вам ограничение в 20Gb. Сколько вам надо?

Comment: я снижал это ограничение до 100 мб, эффекта было ровно ноль

Comment: В чем выражается ноль эффектв? Какой должен быть эффект?